# Pulling lines out of a file Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, while-loop

I want to pull every line in a file that has a certain word in it and format it a certain way using matlab.  I have started to do this but all my code keeps doing is pulling out the first line and repeating it over and over again.  It won't move onto any other line. I dont see how I would fix this. Here is my code.

```
fid=fopen('suspiciousfile.txt');
myLine=fgetl(fid);
countline=0;
while ischar(myLine)
  strfind('Drexel', myLine)
  countline=countline+1;
  fprintf('Line #%d %s.\n', countline,myLine);
end
```

Comment: `fgetl` gets the first line. Where in your code do you jump to and get the next line?

Comment: I'm unsure where to add that in.

Comment: How do I tell it to search the whole file? Its a pretty large file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are after something like this:

```
fid=fopen('suspiciousfile.txt');
countline=0;
myLine=fgetl(fid);
while ischar(myLine)
    countline=countline+1;
    if strfind(myLine, 'Drexel')
        fprintf(1,'Line #%d %s.\n', countline,myLine);
    end
    myLine=fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

A few notes:

You need to call `fgetl` within your loop so that you continue reading new lines.

The arguments to `strfind(TEXT,PATTERN)` where you search for `PATTERN` in `TEXT`

If you only want to print certain lines, you need an `if` statement.

It is good practice to close any file you open with `fclose` when you are done with it.